# Create URL friendly slug with pure bash?

Tags: bash, slug, parameter-expansion

I am after a pure bash solution to "slugify" a variable and that is not as ugly as mine.

> **slugify**: lowercased, shortened to 63 bytes, and with everything except
>   0-9 and a-z replaced with -. No leading / trailing -. A string suitable to use in URL hostnames and domain names is the result. 
>   An input is most likely a series of words with undesired characters in throughout such as:
>
> 'Effrafax_mUKwT'uP7(Garkbit<\1}@NJ"RJ"Hactar*S;-H%x.?oLazlarl(=Zss@c9?qick.:?BZarquonelW{x>g@'k'
>
> Of which a slug would look like:
>   'effrafax-mukwt-up7-garkbit-1-njrjhactar-s-h-x-olazlarl-zss-c9-q'

```
slugify () {
  next=${1//+([^A-Za-z0-9])/-}
  next=${next:0:63}
  next=${next,,}
  next=${next#-}
  next=${next%-}
  echo $next
}
```

Also why doesn't `${next//^-|-$}` strip the prefix and suffix `'-'`? Other suggestions?

Comment: Can you give one such sample URL to test on?

Comment: posting the input entries and expected output will increase your chances to obtain a quick help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using this function, in my bash profile:

```
slugify () {
    echo "$1" | iconv -t ascii//TRANSLIT | sed -r s/[~\^]+//g | sed -r s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/-/g | sed -r s/^-+\|-+$//g | tr A-Z a-z
}
```

Based on: https://gist.github.com/oneohthree/f528c7ae1e701ad990e6

Comment: Works great! Add `-c` to `iconv` to silently discard characters that cannot be converted. https://ss64.com/bash/iconv.html

Answer (score 10):

OS X and linux compatible variant of [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49035906/10148424)

```
slugify () {
    echo "$1" | iconv -c -t ascii//TRANSLIT | sed -E 's/[~^]+//g' | sed -E 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/-/g' | sed -E 's/^-+|-+$//g' | tr A-Z a-z
}
```

Comment: Remember that you can combine multiple sed statements, like this:

Comment: Exchaning `"$1"` with `"$@"` or `"$*"` will allow you to do `$ slugify test test` into `test-test` without the need of quotes (`$ slugify "test test"`)